# Equal Dockerfiles but different base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm barely new to Docker but have played around for a bit. I was able to make a Docker file that just has one line difference between the various host OS. Is there a way to avoid having multiple files like this with just the from line different?

For example:

1. FROM ubuntu:16.04
2. FROM centos:7.4.1708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with Dockerfiles themselves. You can create one Dockerfile as a template and use scripts to generate the various OS flavored Dockerfiles on-demand just before build.

For example, [ElasticSearch Docker](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/blob/master/templates/Dockerfile.j2) uses Jinja2 templates for Dockerfiles. They don't modify the `FROM`, but there's plenty of other templated usage that serves as example.

Comment: Any links/details on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is possible, but it seems to have its limitations.

For instance, say I want to build two images with the same "lower layers" for a cuda 11.4 and cuda 11.8 base image.  Then I can use the following construct:

```
ARGS TARGET="cuda11.8"

# CUDA 11.4 Base (deprecated)
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.4.2-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04 as cuda11.4
# Custom instructions for this base:
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y install  python3.9

# CUDA 11.8 Base
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.4.2-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04 as cuda11.8
# Different custom instructions for the other base 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y install  python3.10


FROM ${TARGET}
[everything shared for the different base image builds]
```

It is also possible to specify the name of the base image directly as ARG.

Build the image with `docker build --build-arg 'TARGET=cuda11.4'` for an image based on cuda11.4 and without an argument for the default base image.

Advantages:

- no "duplicate code", because the shared steps are all listed underneath the last stage

Disadvantages:

- The caller needs to keep track of all the names you give the base images and needs to issue a separate call for every image afaik.
- The shared instructions have to appear in the layers below the "custom" instructions, e.g., if you want to install a different version of a package "later on" (at lower layers of the docker file), that is not directly possible afaik.

**Edit** In my research in trying to accomplish what you described in your question I just saw [a blog post](https://blog.dockbit.com/templating-your-dockerfile-like-a-boss-2a84a67d28e9) with more information that might be interesting.